# Equivalent en français courant, et aussi en linguistique française de "mondegreen"

Tags: traduction, linguistique

Quel est le terme courant en français, et en linguistique française (deux termes s'ils sont différents), équivalents à "mondegreen"?

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mondegreen

En espagnol, c'est par exemple "pomporruta", voir ici:
  https://foro.sinfaltas.com/topic/236/pomporruta

L'étymologie en anglais et en espagnol, et d'autres langues, suit la même logique, avons-nous un mot en français qui a le même genre d'étymologie pour désigner ce mot?

Etymologie de "mondegreen":

> When I was a child, my mother used to read aloud to me from Percy's Reliques, and one of my favorite poems began, as I remember:
>
> Ye Highlands and ye Lowlands,
>   Oh, where hae ye been?
>   They hae slain the Earl o' Moray,
>   And *Lady Mondegreen*.
>
> The correct fourth line is, "*And laid him on the green*".
>
> Wright explained the need for a new term: "The point about what I shall hereafter call mondegreens, since no one else has thought up a word for them, is that they are better than the original."

Comment: L'exemple le plus courant en français étant « c'est vieux comme les robes » (et « enduire d'erreurs », « fier comme un petit banc » etc...). Communément appelées « [déformations populaires](http://www.expressio.fr/expressions/vieux-comme-herode.php) ou « [déformations plaisantes](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/vieux_comme_mes_robes) », je préfère appeler ce genre de tournures des « mots tordus »  même si les mots tordus (référence au [Prince de Motordu](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prince_de_Motordu) de Pef) couvrent un champ plus large.

Comment: Ajout : je viens de trouver [deux autres façons de nommer ce genre de construction](https://www.lexpress.fr/culture/livre/motordu-champignon-olympique_805836.html) : « mots de travers » et « mots en tire-bouchon » que je ne connaissais pas. « Mots de travers » fait tout de suite penser à l'allemand qui dit ça *verhörte Worte* (littéralement « mots entendus de travers »)

Answer (score 2):

Vous parlez d’étymologie, alors commençons par l’histoire de quelques mots sémantiquement proches. Ce qui suit semblera sans doute bien sinueux, mais c’est que ma proposition me semble encore imparfaite. Je crois à vrai dire, qu’ elle a besoin du secours de quelques précisions pour sembler éventuellement convaincante.

La relation entre les expressions que vous présentez semble relever de la paronymie. Les expressions *« laid him on the green »* et *« Lady Mondegreen »* présentent une « certaine analogie phonétique, mais sans avoir le même sens » (*TLF*, art. « paronyme »).
Cette paronymie étant aussi essentiellement « vicieuse » (selon le mot du *Robert historique de la langue française*, art. « Barbare »), il s’agit plus précisément d’un *barbarisme*.

Petit excursus philologique. Le *Robert historique* précise façon intéressante que *barbarismus* vient du *barbarismos* d’Aristote. Or, la paronymie est étudiée par Aristote lorsqu’il traite de la question de l’Être dans les *Catégories*, précisément pour dire que l’on entend « Être » en divers sens. De là, Aristote entre dans la discussion du lien entre ces divers sens (sont-ils synonymes, homophones ou simplement paronymes ?)

Le problème, pour ce qui nous intéresse, est que le terme est employé dans un sens très spécifique (comme « intermédiaire entre homonymes et synonymes » comme le note Jules Tricot dans sa traduction des *Catégories* chez Vrin en 1936), qui n’est pas comparable au sens linguistique moderne (sur ce point, on pourra se référer à l’article d’Yvan Pelletier, « Les paronymes » – *Cahiers de l’Institut de philosophie comparée*, 1979, disponible en ligne).

Au sens moderne, le barbarisme consiste, pour ce qui nous intéresse, à « déform[er] grossièrement un mot ou une expression » (Girodet, *Pièges et difficultés de la langue française*, Bordas, 1986, art. « Barbarisme »). Le mot possède aussi un sens plus large, comme le remarque Adolphe Victor Thomas : « Dans le langage courant, on étend le sens de barbarisme à toute faute contre la langue. » (*Dictionnaire des difficultés de la langue française*, Larousse, 1971, art. « Barbarisme »). Cet ouvrage donne une liste assez longue de fautes de barbarismes, mais qui ne relèvent pas vraiment du sens qui nous occupe ici, il s’agit plutôt d’erreurs sur un terme ou sur la syntaxe d’une expression (donc plus précisément d’un solécisme).

Un exemple à mon sens convaincant de ce qui nous occupe ici a été donné par un intervenant *supra* : c’est celui « d’enduire en erreur » (pour « induire en erreur »). Il s’agit très clairement d’un barbarisme, et cette qualification est clairement liée à un problème phonologique (c’est donc bien par paronymie que le barbarisme advient).

Là commence le problème : trouver un terme ou une expression qui présente ce sens de « barbarisme par paronymie » comme un exemple typique, au point d’en devenir l’archétype, puis le *definiendum* (c.-à-d. que ce soit un « barbarisme par paronymie » qui évoque toutes les autres expressions du même type).

Une seule idée me vient, qui ne répond qu’imparfaitement à la question, mais dont l’étymologie fait écho à celles des expressions que vous citez.
Il s’agit du *pataquès*. Le Grand Robert historique précise qu’il est formé par « imitation comique de la faute de la liaison *je ne sais pas-t-à qu’*(qui) *est-ce.* » Par extension, il désigne en effet « un discours confus » (*id.*), mais lorsque l’on parle d’un pataquès, on réalise cette opération qui consiste à utiliser un « barbarisme par paronymie » comme archétype et par suite *definiendum* de tous les autres.

En ce sens, il me semble que ce mot pourrait être celui que vous cherchez.

Answer (score -1):

« Hallucination auditive » est un terme assez convaincant, que je ne connaissais pas mais qui semble avoir un certain crédit ([réf.](https://www.unedeplus.fr/2012/11/15/ce-que-sont-les-mondegreen-et-les-soramimi/)).

Il y a aussi le mot d'origine japonaise « soramimi », nom d'une hallucination auditive qui implique en addition que le son corresponde non pas à des mots dans la même langue mais à des mots dans une langue étrangère.

Il faut cependant se rendre compte que c'est un terme d'origine médical, emprunté à la psychologie, où il ne signifie pas exactement la même chose. On parle conjointement dans ce domaine de paracousie ou hallucination auditive ; il s'agit alors d'une affection « associée à des troubles psychotiques comme la schizophrénie ou la manie,[…mais …] il n'est pas impossible qu'un individu puisse entendre une ou plusieurs voix sans souffrir d'aucun trouble mental spécifique » ([réf.](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hallucination)).

Il me semble qu'il n'y ait pas d'autre terme et étant donné un contexte général existant, celui de l'appellation bien établie d'un phénomène optique bien connu, il me semble que l'on puisse faire beaucoup mieux ; je veux parler du terme « illusion d'optique » ([réf.](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Illusion_d%27optique)). En conséquence je crois que l'on peut continuer sur ce modèle de façon très consistante et parler dans le cas du son d'« illusion d'acoustique », le terme « illusion » étant un correcteur approprié du mot non juste « hallucination ».